# Which url should I use to post data in dotnet api?

Tags: .net, angular

I am new to dotnet. I am trying to post data from Angular Service to api. The api method is:

```
  [Route("api/v1/booking")]


/// <param name="schedule"></param>
 [HttpPost("appointment")]
 public async Task<ActionResult> ScheduleAppointment([FromBody] AppointmentRequest schedule)
```

I am trying to send it to the url `/booking/appointment`. It returns url not found. I tried with schedule didn't work either. Am I doing wrong somewhere else. I want to know which url is correct.

Below is angular service:

```
private readonly bookAppointmentUrl: string = '/booking/appointment';
 const x = this.http.post(this.bookAppointmentUrl, appointmentRequest, this.getRequestHeaders()).pipe(
      tap(r => console.log(r)),
      catchError(error => {
        return this.handleError(error, () => this.bookAppointment(appointmentRequest));
      }));
```

Comment: you should show us the angular service..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use absolute path of api controller.

Example: `*wep-api-address*/api/v1/booking/appointment`

*web-api-address* is where your api running (e.g localhost:5000)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understand I need to use absolute address, I am just confused with which route it is.  So, **/booking/appointment is correct. May be I am doing wrong somewhere else.

Comment: I assumed that route attribute belongs to controller.

Comment: The first route is to controller. I am confused is it 'appointment' or not for the post request.